# Azure Devops - hosted XML: Conditional based Rules

Tags: azure-devops

we are using azure devops hosted xml process.
i am trying to set Field A as required when Field B equals to Field C but the comparison do not work with i compare two reference fields.
if i compare a reference field to a specific value it works, but i need to compare 2 fields.
This is the comparison (G.CR and G.FixFor both equal 815)

```
    <FIELD refname="G.BugReason">
       <WHEN field="G.CR" value="G.FixFor">  
           <REQUIRED />  
       </WHEN> 
    </FIELD>
```

both of the fields are defined as strings.
it does work when i do the following comparison (when G.CR equals 815):

```
    <FIELD refname="G.BugReason">
       <WHEN field="G.CR" value="815">  
           <REQUIRED />  
       </WHEN> 
    </FIELD>
```

please help.
thanks.
Guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario you ask about isn't supported.

> You can define conditions that are based on what value is assigned to
>   a specific field or whether a user modifies a specific field.

According to our official doc -- [Assign conditional-based values and rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules?view=azure-devops-2019). It's not able to directly compare two field as a conditional-based rules.

You could create a related user voice and vote up in our [feature request page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea) from Developer Community site. Our PM will kindly review your suggestion.

[image]